# Change all values in a column.

Tags: r

I've just started programing with R and have problem with solving an easy task.. So I have a dataframe with a column where all my values starts with DB- and I want to remove the "DB-" from my values. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with `gsub()`, like so:

```
data$column <- gsub("DB-","",data$column)
```